# Get collections within an Entity when mapping it to DTO using Transformers

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dto

I have an Entity called Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Integer studentId;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String studentName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Note> studentNotes;

    // Some other instance variables that are not relevant to this question

    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

and an entity called as Note

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
public class Note implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "NOTE_ID")
    private Integer noteId;

    @Column(name = "NOTE_CONTENT")
    private String noteText;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Student student;

    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

As you can see the relationship dictates that a Student can have multiple number of notes.

For displaying some information about the student on a particular page I need only the studentName, count of notes and all the notes. 
I created a StudentDTO for that and it looks something like this:

```
public class StudentDTO {

    private Long count;
    private String name;
    private List<Note> notes;

    /* Getters and setters */

}
```

And I am using the following code to map the Student and Notes returned from the DB to the StudentDTO

```
private static void testDTO() {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String queryString = "SELECT count(n) as count, s.studentName as name, s.studentNotes as notes " +
                "from Student s join s.studentNotes n where s.id = 3";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);

        List<StudentDTO> list = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class)).list();
        for (StudentDTO u : list) {
            System.out.println(u.getName());
            System.out.println(u.getCount());
            System.out.println(u.getNotes().size());
        }
    }
```

The above code fails when there are notes fetched in the query but if I remove the notes and get only name and count it works fine.

When notes is included in the query, this is the error that is fired by Hibernate:

```
select
            count(studentnot2_.NOTE_ID) as col_0_0_,
            . as col_3_0_,
            studentnot3_.NOTE_ID as NOTE_ID1_2_,
            studentnot3_.NOTE_CONTENT as NOTE_CON2_2_,
            studentnot3_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT_3_2_ 
        from
            students studentx0_ 
        inner join
            notes studentnot2_ 
                on studentx0_.STUDENT_ID=studentnot2_.STUDENT_ID 
        inner join
            notes studentnot3_ 
                on studentx0_.STUDENT_ID=studentnot3_.STUDENT_ID 
        where
            studentx0_.STUDENT_ID=3;
```

And this is the error message that I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_3_0_, studentnot3_.NOTE_ID as NOTE_ID1_2_, studentnot3_.NOTE_CONTENT as N' at line 1
```

Now I can see where the query is wrong but it is generated by Hibernate, not something that I have control on. Is there something that I need to change in my queryString to acheive the result that I need.

I do not want to manually map the results to my DTO, is there a way that I can directly map my studentNotes in Student.java to notes in StudentDTO.java

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this query is wrong. The better way is to get just the student. You can always get collection of notes from a student.

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
String queryString = from Student s where s.studentId = 3;
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
Student student = query.getSingleResult();
sysout(student.getNotes().size())
```

Also, I never retrieved collection this way in SELECT clause; so, not sure but do you really need

```
join s.studentNotes
```

in your query? Not sure if my answer is helpful.

Comment: But this beats the purpose of DTO. I will have to manually populate the fields of StudentDTO

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong as you would need two joins to also select the count of notes, but that's not even necessary, as you could determine the count by just using the size of the notes collection.

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for your example could look like this

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
interface StudentDTO {
  @Mapping("studentName")
  String getName();
  @Mapping("studentNotes")
  List<NoteDTO> getNotes();
  default int getCount() { return getNotes().size(); }
}

@EntityView(Note.class)
interface NoteDTO {
  // attributes of Note that you need
  @IdMapping Integer getId();
  String getNoteText();
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
StudentDTO student = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, StudentDTO.class, studentId);
```